# ptyhon mysql the query result is always the same (in loop)

Tags: python, mysql

The Percentages tab is regularly updated every 60 seconds by another python process.
In the cycle every 10 seconds I check the table but I always have only one result.

```
from pickle import TRUE 
import ccxt 
import mysql.connector
from datetime import datetime, date
import time 
mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="127.0.0.1",
  user="xxxxx",
  password="xxxxxx",
  database="xxxx"
)
mycursor = mydb.cursor()

cl = 0
while True:
  now = datetime.now()
  date_time = now.strftime("%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S")
  cls = str(cl)
  print (date_time + ' start ' + cls + ' cycle\n')
  sql= "select * from Percentuali order by Id desc limit 1"
  mycursor.execute(sql)
  myresult = mycursor.fetchone()
  print (myresult)
 
# end ---------------
```

Output:

```
(203, datetime.datetime(2022, 4, 29, 12, 15, 11), -0.0222675, None)
(203, datetime.datetime(2022, 4, 29, 12, 15, 11), -0.0222675, None)
(203, datetime.datetime(2022, 4, 29, 12, 15, 11), -0.0222675, None)
(203, datetime.datetime(2022, 4, 29, 12, 15, 11), -0.0222675, None)
```

... every time.

I'm testing on a raspberry with mariadb 10 (10.0.28-MariaDB-2 + b1 Raspbian testing-staging) and use heidisql to verify that the update is successful

Answer (score 0):

Resolved:

```py
sql= "select * from Percentuali order by Id desc limit 1"
mycursor.execute(sql)
myresult = mycursor.fetchone()
mydb.commit()
```